# Iterate through a Pandas Dataframe and get the values and row numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Supposing that I have this Pandas Dataframe:

```
          0       1
1      NaN   (9, 5)
9    (8, 3)     NaN
10   (8, 2)     NaN
11   (8, 1)     NaN
```

What is the most efficient way to get the values of all columns with their respective row numbers ignoring the NaN values? For example, for the above dataframe I would like to return something like:

```
Return:

(8,3) -> Row Number 9, Column 0
(8,2) -> Row Number 10, Column 0
(8,1) -> Row Number 11, Column 0
(9,5) -> Row Number 1, Column 1
```

**Obs:** The dataframe proposed is just a example, the one I will use have more rows and columns and the dataframe values are random tuples or NaN values

Answer (score 3):

You can do `stack`

```
df.stack()
1   1    (9,5)
9   0    (8,3)
10  0    (8,2)
11  0    (8,1)
dtype: object
```

the index is the position

```
df.stack().index
MultiIndex([( 1, '1'),
            ( 9, '0'),
            (10, '0'),
            (11, '0')],
           )
```

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S, thanks for the help! I'm really new to Pandas, so there's any way to iterate this stack? I need to pass the row number, column number, and value to another function.